# How can I only select points in Edit Mode?

Tags: edit-mode, select

I'm new here. I was just watching a tutorial but encountered a problem. The guy in the video only marked the individual points in edit mode so that they were selected in blue (see image). Does anyone know how this works? Thanks in advance :)

Tutorial link: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kGUjDyvhtYw (2:35)

[image]

Comment: Please add your image directly into your question rather than expecting folks to click on a link to see it. https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491/how-to-upload-an-image-to-a-post. It's also not very clear because you haven't used Blender's Window > Save Screenshot menu to create the image.

Comment: Without any commentary to that video or sight of other objects in Edit mode, it's impossible to even guess how he's done that although the answer from @Cornivius could be correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That looks like he's probably using custom colors. You can edit most UI colors on the Edit->Preferences->Themes menu.

[image]

Edit: Looking at the posted tutorial it looks like the only thing he has done is change the color of the unselected vertices from black to light blue. I don't think they are selected since they turn orange when he selects them with the group